# Why can't I just conclude that the equation system is inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving the linear equation system given by the following augmented matrix:
$$
\mathbf{M}=
\left[\begin{array}{r|r}
\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{b}
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2&(3+a)&2&(2+a)\\
1&a&2&a\\
a&2&2a&0
\end{array}\right]
$$

I need to solve this for the cases:

1. $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$
2. $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$

This was my approach:

- *(solving the first case - when $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$)*

For this case, I simply assumed that $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$ and did the necessary row operations to bring $\mathbf{M}$ to its reduced row echelon form as follows

[image]
(please note that I have uploaded this picture because apparently stackexchange will not accept my latex code even though it works in Overleaf. When I paste it here, I get "Misplaced &" - anyway here is the latex code if it helps: https://justpaste.it/72ver).

and the solution is given by

$$
\mathbf{x} = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-\frac{a^2+4}{a^2-2}\\
\frac{a^2}{a^2-2}\\
\frac{a^2-2a+4}{2(a^2-2)}
\end{array}\right]
\text{where } a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}
$$

This is the correct solution but I would have divided by 0 when $a = 3$ - **How would you have avoided this and can't you just ignore this case since the end-result is correct?**

- *(solving the second case - when $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$)*

Now to solve this case, I simply argued that if $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$, I would divide by $0$ in the solution set plus the found solution is a *unique* solution. I was thinking that you would simply replace $a$ with some constant expression like $\pm \sqrt{2}$ in the solution set for any arbitrary $a$ and it would all be fine - it makes sense to me. My answer to this case included the fact that when $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$, the system is inconsistent - which actually is the correct.

HOWEVER, I was told that this approach to the second case is *incorrect*. I was told that my solution depends on $a$ and while I agree, I cannot see how it would change the final solution plus my answer to the second case about the inconsistency - which was correct.

**So how should I solve/answer the second case correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure to find a solution by a certain method is not conclusive evidence of the nonexistence of a solution.

What you should do is to go ahead and substitute $a = \pm\sqrt{2}$ and then proceed to do row operations to derive an appropriate normal form for the augmented matrix. At some point, you will come upon a matrix which has a row like this:
$$(0 \,\, 0 \,\, 0 \,\, | \,\, c) \qquad c \ne 0
$$
at which point you may conclude that the system is inconsistent, because that row is shorthand for the equation
$$0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 = c
$$
which obviously has no solutions given that $c \ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks :) But why would i redo the whole process from the first case, just with a substituted with $\pm \sqrt{2}$, if I actually was able to give the correct conclusion - that the system is consistent in this case?

Comment: So 1. it would be amazing if you could elaborate a bit and thus also answer my comment above. 2. what would you do to avoid the issue with $a = 3$ in the first case (this is not as important for me as the other question though)? Thanks again!! I appreciate it

Comment: @npp You do have to deal with the case $a=3$ separately. Your row-reduction includes an invalid operation in that case. You could argue that when $a\ne\pm\sqrt2$, the coefficient matrix is nonsingular.

Comment: You don't have to redo the *whole* process, you can go up to the step before the illegal operation would have occurred for $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$; that would be the step where you divide through by $a^2-2$. Instead of doing that, you substitute $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$ at that point, and continue from there (probably there won't be much left to do).

Comment: @amd thanks to you both. But amd - what do you mean by "you can argue that when $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$, the coefficient matrix is nonsingular"? What does this mean with regards the invalid operation when $a = 3$? Does that allow me to ignore it? If so, why?

Comment: @LeeMosher Okay, thanks! But I still do not get, like 100%, why I would have to replace $a$ when there is only *one* reduced echelon form of a matrix? Could you elaborate a tiny bit more or point me to what part of your answer that I am not reading correctly, please? I know I may sound a little dumb :P

Comment: Whether or not there is only one reduced echelon form of a matrix, there are correct ways to calculate it, and incorrect ways to calculate it. Any calculation that ends with a zero in some denominator is guaranteed to be incorrect. The point is that different values of $a$ will result in different paths of calculation. Yes, those paths of calculation may be the same for a while, but at some point they may diverge.

Comment: You are already familiar with this kind of thing. If I ask you to calculate the roots of the equation $ax-2x=0$, there are two different calculation paths: one for the case $a\ne 2$, and another for the case $a=2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Lee! I really appreciate your patience with me

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Comment: @npp If a square matrix $A$ is nonsingular, then for all $b$ (for which the equation makes sense at all, of course) the equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution.